# Handling the Duplicate and Order of the message in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Trying to understand the difference between following configuration  to handle Order of the message and Duplicate message in Kafka .  I could not find any detailed explanation in anywhere . 
Could you please help me understand with some use case .

```
enable.idempotence=true
```

Idempotent producers can handle duplicate messages and preserve message order even with request pipelining—there is no message duplication because the broker ignores duplicate sequence numbers, and message ordering is preserved because when there are failures, the producer temporarily constrains to a single message in flight until sequencing is restored.

`max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1` to ensure that only one request can be sent to the broker at a time. To preserve message order while allowing request pipelining, set the configuration 
parameter retries=0 if the application is able to tolerate some message loss

Answer (score 0):

When you set `enable.idempotence=true` these configurations are automatically set if you don't set them manually.

```
retries=Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

`max.in.flight.requests=5` (if Kafka version >= 1.0 You can check [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5494) for more information.)

```
acks=all
```

And this is the ideal configuration for idempotent producer. If you set `retries=0`, in case of network failure you couldn't even send the message to broker.

> **enable.idempotence:** When set to 'true', the producer will ensure that exactly one copy of each message is written in the stream. If
>   'false', producer retries due to broker failures, etc., may write
>   duplicates of the retried message in the stream. Note that enabling
>   idempotence requires max.in.flight.requests.per.connection to be less
>   than or equal to 5, ***retries to be greater than 0*** and acks must be
>   'all'. If these values are not explicitly set by the user, suitable
>   values will be chosen. If incompatible values are set, a
>   ConfigException will be thrown.